# Microsoft oAuth redirecting to root instead of "home" url when using microsoft Azure application authentication

Tags: azure, redirect, model-view-controller, oauth-2.0

I am using ASP.NET MVC with "sign in with microsoft" as the login.

First, everything works on localhost.

I have registered my app on the AZ portal, with a redirect URL of `https://xxxxxxx.com/xxx/Home/Index`. I have a web.config redirect uri that matches

When I publish the application and sign in with microsoft it authenticates, then redirects to https://xxxxxxx.com/xxx/Home/Index as a Post with form data of (string code, string id_token, string state, string session_state) with 302 error

which then redirects to the root `https://xxxxxxx.com`

Comment: What is the issue with this ?

Comment: @RahulShukla  I need it to redirect to home/index, not to xxxxx.com

Comment: Check the custom domain mapping of your application. It seems you have custom domain mapping that's why it getting redirected.

Comment: @RahulShukla thanks for your input. I am not seeing customer domain mapping available. Where would that show up

Comment: what the reply back url you have configured in application registration in azure ad ?

Comment: @RahulShukla
https://xx.com/xx/Home/Index  (xx subs for actual names)

Comment: @RahulShukla oddly enough if I direct them to https://xxxxx/xxx/Claims I do not get the 302 redirect error

Comment: let connect I will try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Update the reply back(redirect url) in application registration.

[image]

Comment: that is where I have the https://xxxxx.com/home/index code  it does redirect there, as a 302 post, then fails over to https://xxxxx.com

Comment: Lets connect will help you rahulshukla422@gmail.com

Comment: @rahul shukla, were you able to fix this? can you please put an answer on it for others to refer? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @Nisarg check your reply back url in app configuration

Answer (score 0):

sorry for delayed reply in your config file after clientID, authority, redirectUrl etc add below -

navigateToLoginRequestUrl:false

Hope this will help

Comment: in which section you put LoginRequestUrl, did you tested ?

Comment: in auth section also I have tested this and works well.